# What is the difference between update and updateClassifiers

Tags: sbt

What is the difference between `update` and `updateClassifiers` ?

In my project I can see:

- `update`: 320M of cache
- `updateClassifiers`: 598M of cache

I can see their descriptions:

- `update`: Resolves and optionally retrieves dependencies, producing a report.
- `updateClassifiers`: Resolves and optionally retrieves classified artifacts, such as javadocs and sources, for dependency definitions, transitively

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the difference that you mentioned in the question itself:

`update` - do not resolves and retrieves anything that have classifier `javadoc` or `source`, while `updateClassifiers` will do that, that's why the cache is bigger.

Comment: A ok, thanks. Actually I didn't know that javadocs or sources where classifiers